# how to create .csr file (SSL) on command line or api (Visual Basic or Other programming language) for IIS 6.0 / 7.0

Tags: visual-studio, iis-7, iis-6

i need creating .csr file on vb api or command line tool for iis 6.0 / 7.0.

thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are many pages with GUI wizards explaining how to do this](http://www.dotster.com/ssl/csr/help/micro).  IIS (at least through v6) has never been friendly to programmatic manipulation.

Command line options appear to mostly rely on openssl.  [Here is a page that code generates the command line invocation you need](https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm).

And [section #3 of the openssl cert faq](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt).

Weigh carefully the benefits of writing code for what might be faster to do with an annoying GUI.